# OPENSSL S_CLIENT stuck at CONNECTED(00000003)

Tags: ssl, openssl, client-server, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying a TLS connection to aws_iot core using openssl s_client.

```
openssl s_client -connect ajvldjdsdggr-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883 -CAfile AmazonRootCA1.crt
cert 6fceaadfd6a-certificate.pem.crt -key 6fceaadfd6a-private.pem.key
```

**OUTPUT RECIEVED**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

And it is stuck at this point.

Can anyone please explain what might be the issue?

Comment: Why do you think there is an issue? The client has connected to the broker, it is now expecting the client to send a MQTT CONNECT packet (which s_client will not be able to do)

Comment: Because running from another PC gives me a server certificate